# Url.routeUrl returns null (I've tried same questions)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi everyone I wanna get url like {Controller}/{action}/{postid}-{address}
but routUrl returns null please help me to solve it.(I'm newbie in MVC)

my route config is

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Post",
            url: "Posts/Show/{postid}-{address}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Posts", action = "Index", postid = "", address = "" }
           );
```

and index.cshtml

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Post",new {item.PostId,item.Address })">@item.PostTitle</a>
```

the url that generate is
http://localhost:59066/Posts/Show/1-Post-with-Featured-Image

but in PostsController

```
public ActionResult Show(string add)
    { return View();}
```

"string add" is null !

Comment: Your parameter `add` does not match either `{postid}` or `{address}`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the route to

```
routes.MapRoute("Post", "post/{postid}-{address}", new { controller = "Posts", action = "Show" ,postid="",address=""}, namespaces);
```

and added a route with same controller and action

```
routes.MapRoute("PostAddress", "post/{IdAndAdd}", new { controller = "Posts", action = "Show" }, namespaces);
routes.MapRoute("Post", "post/{postid}-{address}", new { controller = "Posts", action = "Show" ,postid="",address=""}, namespaces);
```

then action received "idAndAdd" correctly

```
public ActionResult Show(string idAndAdd)
    {
        var parts = SeperateAddress(idAndAdd);
        if (parts == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        var post = db.Posts.Find(parts.Item1);
        if (post == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        if (!post.Address.Equals(parts.Item2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return RedirectToRoutePermanent("Post", new { postid = parts.Item1, address = post.Address });

        return View(post);
    }

    and it's worked .
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change the Routes...

try this...

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action","Controller",new {PostId = item.PostId, Address = item.Address })">@item.PostTitle</a>
```

This will send PostId and Address as parameters, so you can get them in the controller like:

```
public ActionResult AwesomeThings(int PostId, String Address)
{
         var foo = PostId;
         var bar = Address;
        return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No changes in routing,

Index.cshtml:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Post",new {@postid = item.PostId, @address = item.Address },null)">@item.PostTitle</a>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Show(string postid, string address)
{ return View();}
```